# Bounds condition for IFT to obtain a $1/f$ time-series

Tags: computational-physics, fourier-transform, data-analysis

I am coding a function to obtain a randomized time-series from a given $\frac{1}{f}$ law.
The randomization is obtained by introducing a random phase in the function.

I experience a problem in the simulated time-series, the values systematically rise.
I suppose it is something related to the definition of the function itself.

The written function is reported in the following:

```py
def Pk(k, alpha=-11.0 / 3, fknee=1):
    """Simple power law formula with ASD"""
    return (k / fknee) ** alpha


def gen_pkfield(nsample=100, alpha=-11.0 / 3, fknee=1, fsample=2.5):
    
    ufreq = np.fft.fftfreq(n=nsample+1, d=1./fsample)   # the Discrete Fourier Transform sample frequencies (with negative values)
    kfreq = np.sqrt(ufreq ** 2) # to create the positive one
    

    with np.errstate(divide="ignore"):
        asd_per = Pk(kfreq, alpha=alpha, fknee=fknee)   # there is a factor sqrt(2) for the ASD


    pha = np.random.uniform(low=-np.pi, high=np.pi, size=(nsample+1) )
    
    asd_random = asd_per * (np.cos(pha) + 1j * np.sin(pha))     # frequency domain signal with random phase
        
    psd_per = asd_random[1:]**2.    # psd periodogram with random phase 
    psd_norm =  psd_per  * (fsample*nsample/2.) 
    asd_norm = np.sqrt(psd_norm ) 
    
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(asd_norm)
    plt.ylabel(r'Amplitude spectral density [Hz/$\sqrt{Hz}$] ')
    plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
    plt.tight_layout()  
    
    ifft = np.real( np.fft.ifft( asd_norm )  )     # reverse the normalization for ifft coherence   
    
    return ifft
```

The various normalizations which I introduced are to make the `numpy.ifft` compatible with the `scipy.periodogram` (from which I take the $\alpha$ and $knee$ values).

Here the ASD obtained (named `asd_norm` in the function).
This is obtained with $\alpha=0.9$ and $knee=0.148$

[image: ASD]

And here the result for a simulated time-series:

[image: Time-series]

As you can see, the time-series values rise at the bounds. I wonder why.

---

## NEW

I corrected things inside the function.
I mixed up PSD and ASD.
Here the new definition:

```py
def gen_pkfield(nsample=100, alpha=-11.0 / 3, fknee=1, fsample=2.5): # sampling per block
    
    ufreq = np.fft.fftfreq(n=nsample, d=1./fsample)     # the Discrete Fourier Transform sample frequencies (with negative values)
    kfreq = np.sqrt(ufreq[:] ** 2 + ufreq ** 2)
    with np.errstate(divide="ignore"):
        psd_per = Pk(kfreq, alpha=alpha, fknee=fknee)   # there is a factor sqrt(2) for the ASD
            
    asd_per = psd_per * np.sqrt( fsample*nsample/2. )   # psd periodogram with random phase
    
            
    pha = np.random.uniform(low=-np.pi, high=np.pi, size=(nsample) )
    asd_norm = asd_per * (np.cos(pha) + 1j * np.sin(pha))   # frequency domain signal with random phase

    
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(kfreq,asd_norm,'k-')
    plt.ylabel(r'Amplitude spectral density [Hz/$\sqrt{Hz}$] ')
    plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
    plt.tight_layout()  
    
    ifft = np.real( np.fft.ifft( asd_norm )  )     # reverse the normalization for ifft coherence   
    
    
    return ifft
```

[image]

The major issue now is that I obtain just `inf` values.

==============

### SOLVED

By deleting the DC component (frequency = 0 Hz)

```py
def gen_pkfield(nsample=100, alpha=-11.0 / 3, fknee=1, fsample=2.5): # sampling per block
    
    ufreq = np.fft.fftfreq(n=nsample+1, d=1./fsample)[1:]   # the Discrete Fourier Transform sample frequencies (with negative values), [1:] to solve the DC
    kfreq = np.sqrt(ufreq[:] ** 2 + ufreq ** 2)
        
    with np.errstate(divide="ignore"):
        psd_per = Pk(kfreq, alpha=alpha, fknee=fknee)   # there is a factor sqrt(2) for the ASD
            
    asd_per = np.sqrt( psd_per * fsample*nsample/2. )   # psd periodogram with random phase
            
    pha = np.random.uniform(low=-np.pi, high=np.pi, size=(nsample) )
    asd_norm = asd_per * (np.cos(pha) + 1j * np.sin(pha))   # frequency domain signal with random phase 

    ifft = np.real( np.fft.ifft( asd_norm )  )     # reverse the normalization for ifft coherence   
    
    return ifft
```

Comment: I have already found a problem, I badly mixed the ASD and PSD in the last part of the topic.

Comment: You can remove the updated SOLVED update from the question, since you include this as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the solution, a function to create a randomized time-series starting from a PSD:

````py
def gen_pkfield(nsample=100, alpha=-11.0 / 3, fknee=1, fsample=2.5): # sampling per block
    
    ufreq = np.fft.fftfreq(n=nsample+1, d=1./fsample)[1:]   # the Discrete Fourier Transform sample frequencies (with negative values), [1:] to solve the DC
    kfreq = np.sqrt(ufreq[:] ** 2 + ufreq ** 2)
        
    with np.errstate(divide="ignore"):
        psd_per = Pk(kfreq, alpha=alpha, fknee=fknee)   # there is a factor sqrt(2) for the ASD
            
    asd_per = np.sqrt( psd_per * fsample*nsample/2. )   # psd periodogram with random phase
            
    pha = np.random.uniform(low=-np.pi, high=np.pi, size=(nsample) )
    asd_norm = asd_per * (np.cos(pha) + 1j * np.sin(pha))   # frequency domain signal with random phase 

    ifft = np.real( np.fft.ifft( asd_norm )  )     # reverse the normalization for ifft coherence   
    
    return ifft 
```
````